# SUM(IF(ColA=ColA AND ColB=ColB,ColC,0)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, worksheet-function, sumifs

This SUMIF calculation has stumped me within Excel (2013).

```
A           B            C          D         E    
Created     Source       Conv       Rev       RPConv
Jan,1 2014  Apples       3          5.00      =Rev/Conv
Jan,1 2014  Oranges      2          4.00      =Rev/Conv
Jan,7 2014  Apples       3          5.00      =Rev/Conv
Feb,1 2014  Apples       5          5.00      =Rev/Conv
Feb,1 2014  Oranges      3          4.00      =Rev/Conv
```

CURRENT: `=SUM(IF(MONTH($A:$A)=1 AND $B:$B='Apples',$D:$D,0)`

What I expect to return is:

```
5.00+5.00
```

but unfortunately it rejects the statement altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the tag and assuming Month 1 is January 2014:

```
=SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,">"&41639,A:A,"<"&41671,B:B,"Apples")
```

Comment: This would be my preference, although I'd prefer using DATE function, e.g. `">="&DATE(2014,1,1)`....or a cell ref

Comment: Hey pnuts! It may be unnecessary in many cases but I always prefer formulas that will work irrespective of "Date system" - `41639` could represent two different dates depending on date system....and to me `41639` is not obviously 31st Dec 2013......just nit-picking, though!

Answer (score -2):

```
=SUM(IF(AND(MONTH($A:$A)=1,$B:$B="Apples"),$D:$D,0))
```

Comment: Hello @ejlj, i no longer receive an error but I am receiving a 0 return.  I definitely have records that match TRUE to both logical tests of being in January and having a source code of Apples.

Comment: Have you used SUMPRODUCT ? I'm not sure what your purpose is but it could be something like this:
=SUMPRODUCT(--(D:D),--(B:B="green"),--(MONTH(C:C)=1)) 'if month = january

Comment: You can't use `AND` in these type of formulas because AND retuns a single value rather than an array - to make it work with this kind of setup you need *, i.e. `=SUM(IF((MONTH($A:$A)=1)*($B:$B="Apples"),$D:$D))` but that's slow.......